# Chart js PHP and JSON wont diplsay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, chart.js

I am trying to get JSON through PHP. This is successful since the console display the json objects. 
But the values will not display on the chart.

Is there something wrong with the way I translate JSON?

```
// Getting PHP - JSON file
$.get('chartBar.php', {type: "bar"}, function(dataBar){
    console.log(dataBar);

//Translate JSON
    var chartjsDataBar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataBar.length; i++) {
    chartjsDataBar.push(dataBar[i].data); 
    };

    var BarChartData = {
        labels : labelTags,
        datasets: [
        {        
        label: "Net Comp",
        fillColor : "#F02626",
        strokeColor : "#F02626",
        pointColor : "#F02626",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "#F02626",
        data : chartjsDataBar[0]},
        {
        label: "AnalyzerHR",
        fillColor : "#26F041",
        strokeColor : "#26F041",
        pointColor : "#26F041",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "#26F041",
        data : chartjsDataBar[1]},
        {
        label: "Question Right",
        fillColor : "#20AEFA",
        strokeColor : "#20AEFA",
        pointColor : "#20AEFA",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "#20AEFA",
        data : chartjsDataBar[2]}

    ]};
```

If I add the data straight like this `data : dataBar` it displays but of course the results are all mixed in one line.

PHP :

```
    <?php

    $array = [
        [  
    "label"=> "Net Comp",
    "color"=> "#F02626",
    "data"=> [0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
], [
    "label"=> "AnalyzerHR",
    "color"=> "#26F041",
    "data"=> [ 0, 4, 3, 5, 7,  2 ]
], [
    "label"=> "Question Right",
    "color"=> "#20AEFA",
    "data"=> [ 0, 3, 1,  3,  3, 1] 
]
    ];

    if($_GET['type'] == "bar"){
        echo json_encode($array);   
    }
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't you need to set the `$.get` to `json` so it knows the dataType coming back? Like `$.get('chartBar.php', {type: "bar"}, function(dataBar){},'json');`

Comment: Oh I didnt add the ,'json' at the end. Yes thank you :)

Comment: Great, I just added as answer for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `$.get` to receive `json` so it knows the dataType coming back.

`$.get('chartBar.php', {type: "bar"}, function(dataBar){},'json');`